# Passing data to subreport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am a a beginner in this topic.
In my Java code I create a HQL query:

```
List <User> listOfDetails = session.createQuery("from User").list();
```

I would like to fill my subreport using data form above query.
How should I complete the following code:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{listOfDetails})]]></dataSourceExpression>`.

Comment: Thanks, I solve this by passing a parameter. Your answer was very helpful.